# A question about the parallelism in h2o.grid() function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, h2o, grid-search, h2o.ai

I try to use the `h2o.grid()` function from the h2o package to do some tuning using R, when I set the parameter `parallelism` larger then 1, it always shows the warning

> Some models were not built due to a failure, for more details run `summary(grid_object, show_stack_traces = TRUE)

And the model_ids in the final grid object includes many models end with `_cv_1`, `_cv_2` etc, and the number of the models is not equal to the setting of my `max_models` in `search_criteria` list, I think they are just the models in the `cv` process, not the final model.

When I set `parallelism` larger than 1:
[image: when I set "parallelism" larger than 1]

When I leave the `parallelism` default or set it to 1, the result is normal, all models end with `_model_1`, `_model_2` etc.

When I leave the "parallelism" default or set it to 1:
[image: when I leave the "parallelism" default or set it to 1]

Here is my code:

```
# set the grid
rf_h2o_grid <- list(mtries = seq(3, ncol(train_h2o), 4),
                    max_depth = c(5, 10, 15, 20))

# set the search_criteria
sc <- list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", 
           seed = 100,
           max_models = 5
           )

# random grid tuning
rf_h2o_grid_tune_random <- h2o.grid(
  algorithm = "randomForest", 
  x = x, 
  y = y,
  training_frame = train_h2o,
  nfolds = 5,                     # use cv to validate the parameters
  fold_assignment = "Stratified",   
  ntrees = 100,
  seed = 100,
  hyper_params = rf_h2o_grid,
  search_criteria = sc
  # parallelism = 6           # when I set it larger than 1, the result always includes some "cv_" models
  )
```

So how can I use the `parallelism` correctly in `h2o.grid()`? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an actual issue with parallelism in grid search, previously noticed but not reported correctly.
Thanks for raising this, we'll try to fix it soon: see https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7886 if you want to track progress.

Until proper fix, you must avoid using both CV and parallelism in your grids.

Regarding the following error:

> Some models were not built due to a failure, for more details run `summary(grid_object, show_stack_traces = TRUE)

if the error is reproducible, you should be getting more details by running the grid with `verbose=True`.
Adding the entire error message to the ticket above might also help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is helpful! I will avoid using both cv and parallelism in `h2o.grid()` for a while.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set max_models = 5, your grid will only make 5 models then stop.

There are three ways to set up early stopping criteria:

1. "max_models": max number of models created
2. "max_runtime_secs": max running time in seconds
3. metric-based early stopping by setting up for "stopping_rounds",  "stopping_metric", and "stopping_tolerance"